# Doubts about a group of order four

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I know that a group of four elements may be written as $\{e, a, b, c\}$, where $ab=c$.

I want to prove that $ab$ is different from $a$, $b$ and $e$. The first two cases are trivial, but I couldn't prove that $ab$ is different from $e$. How can I do this?

Note: I am reading Gallian, and he denoted (in the example 3 of the external direct product's section (page 163)) an abstract group of four elements so (i.e. $\{e,a,b,ab\}$). Then, it seems that $ab$ is the 'four' element of this group.

Comment: If those are the four elements of the group, then all four elements must be distinct. Else the group would only contain three elements.

Comment: Sometimes in a group of order 4 we *do* have $ab=e$.

Comment: I need to proof that if I have two elements diferent from the identity, the 'four' element of the group is ab. Then I have to proof that ab=e.

Comment: Then you'll fail because we may have a cyclic group with $e, x, x^3, x^2$ as your $e,a,b,c$.

Comment: I am reading Gallian, and he denoted (in the example 3 of the external direct product's section (page 163)) an abstract group of four elements so (i.e $\{e, a, b, ab\}$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement appearing in the classification of groups of order $4$ is slightly different. It is said, that we can **find** $a,b\in G$ such that $G=\{e,a,b,ab\}$. This is different from your claim.

Comment: Oh. How we do that construction?

Comment: See Proposition $1.5.4$ [here](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_54_groups.pdf).

Comment: Thanks you! So, when I have the cyclic group case, can I choose $a^2$ and a?

Comment: Yes, exactly... well $a^2$ and $a$ (not a).

Answer (score 2):

This is not true. In the subgroup $\lbrace 1, i, -1, -i \rbrace$ of $\mathbb{C}^*$ (for the multiplication), take $a=i$ and $b=-i$ : you have $ab=1$.

**Edit :** Indeed, you can find $a,b$ such that this works : for example, take $a=i$ and $b=-1$ here.